# Как в Wireguard перенаправлять трафик с подсети на proxy?

Tags: wireguard

У меня есть 2 компа связанные в свою vpn сеть у одного компа ip подсети 10.0.10.1 у другого 10.0.10.2
как мне направить трафик от 10.0.10.1 на определённый proxy сервер, прокси с авторизацией - ip, port, log, pass

То есть путь такой

ПК -> VPN Сервер -> Proxy -> Интернет